# pretrained object detection models in keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, pytorch

There are pretrained **object recognition** models in keras.applications library. But as far as I know, there is no pretrained **object detection** model available.

Does anyone know why it is the case? Object detection is a big part of problems when dealing with visual problems.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/12940/object-detection-versus-object-recognition this should give you an idea.

Comment: thank you @anand_v.singh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because vanilla Keras does not include implementation of methods/models for object detection.

There are many approaches to object detection with deep learning (see [Object Detection with Deep Learning: A Review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.05511) for a survey), but none of them are implemented as a part of Keras library, so no official models as well. I have a feeling that François Chollet tries to keep it simple and minimalistic, so bloating the code with something like [TensorFlow models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models) will be against its philosophy.

However, Keras is easily extendable, so there are plenty of unofficial implementations (e.g. [SSD](https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras) or [Mask R-CNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN)) supplied with the trained models though. See [Keras model zoo](https://modelzoo.co/framework/keras) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Though applications module has no object detection models included, the repo provides links to some of the community implementations. https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications#reference-implementations-from-the-community